# PrimeNG table is not taking the fixed width in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am trying to fix the width of the first column in the primeNG table but somehow it is overriding my CSS even though it is showing while inspecting the element.

Basically, I am looking for CSS in which by changing the tab the first column of the table will have a fixed width no matter what is the size of all columns.

I have tried following way by defining fixed width for the first child but it is taking based width:100%.

[image]
In the above image, you can see the size is coming as 368 even though it is 100px defined.

Same when I change the tab, the width is coming as 920 even 100px is fixed.

[image]

Is there any way I can define fixed-width 100px with having table width:100% as I don't want to break responsiveness?

Below is reproducible example for reference:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablescroll-demo-wtpbny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've the solution required in one of my projects.

You should perform these steps:

1. Set a width for your desired columns
2. Set the horizontal scroll as per primeng [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table), in Horizontal Scroll section:

> Horizontal Scroll:
> In horizontal scrolling, it is required to give fixed widths to columns. In general when customizing the column widths of scrollable tables, use colgroup as below to avoid misalignment issues as it will apply both the header, body and footer sections which are different separate elements internally.

Here is a live [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablescroll-fixedcolumn?file=src/app/app.component.html) including a fixed size only for first column and a responsive table.

This is the only solution (setting a fixed size for your table) because if you set the width to 100% in a mobile device, probably not all columns will be displayed or will be overlapped, breaking responsiveness.

Answer (score 4):

**In primeng 12 they removed colgroup template so if you are using colgroup over the application need to remove because custom width is not working for column if you are using scrollable check migration guide.**

link:https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/wiki/Migration-Guide

solution:
you need to add same width for both tags <th [style]="'width':'100px'"> and <td [style]="'width':'100px'">
if you are using dynamic columns then add one more property width like below

**[{ header: "Name", field: "name", width: '100px' }] // column object array object**

```
<p-table [value]="data" [columns]="ColumnObjectArray">   
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let col of columns; let idx=index;" class="" 
                           [style]="'width':col.width">{{col.header}}</th>
               </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data let-columns="columns">
                <tr>
                    <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [style]="'width':col.width">
                       {{data[col.field]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
</ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**try this one you will definitely get the responsive width to table and also you will get the custom column and header width**

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is just that your selector for the `th` element is slightly incorrect. You have:

```css
::ng-deep .p-datatable .p-datatable-tbody > tr > th:nth-child(1) {
```

but you just need to use `.p-datatable-thead` instead of `.p-datatable-tbody`:

```css
::ng-deep .p-datatable .p-datatable-thead > tr > th:nth-child(1) {
```

Comment: HI MikeJ, thanks for the answer but still the size of the column is getting fixed. You can check this here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablescroll-demo-wtpbny

Comment: @Bravo, you want the first column to be fixed at 100px, correct? Your StackBlitz is doing exactly that...in Chrome on a Mac, anyway.

Comment: if you click on the change tab and add a row the width is getting change.

Comment: so if there is fewer columns in the table the width is not getting fixed

Comment: Ah, I see. It looks like the second column's width is also being set (to 200px). If you remove that setting and allow that column to take up the remaining width of the table, the first column's width setting will be honored. The table can't honor all column width settings if they don't add up to the full table width, so it's forced to calculate column widths that do cover the full table width.

Comment: I tried that. If I do so my columns are overlap each other if the number of columns increase

Comment: Is there anyway I can maintain the scroll?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix. Removing fixed with for all th elements.
Add this to your style.css

```
.p-datatable .p-datatable-thead > tr > th {
    width: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: It is breaking responsiveness https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablescroll-demo-zzzutm

Comment: columns are overlapping each other

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting `table-layout: auto;` to `.p-datatable table` did the trick:

```
.p-datatable table {
  table-layout: auto;
}
```

Then it will respect the width you give to each `td`